# Corrupted size vs. prev size

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class A, B and C (code snippets illustrating the design below).

```
class A{
 public:
     A() = default;
     // some virtual functions
     virtual ~A() = default;

 private:
     // variables; no pointers
}

class B: public A{
  public:
  ~B() = default;

  protected:
     //variables
}

class C: public A{

protected:
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> cs;
   // other variables

public:
 ~ C() = default;

}
```

In the code I have a of `vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` that I push elements onto and apply resize. The problem is more often than not I keep getting the below error when I run the program.

```
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
```

The code base is quite big, so it is difficult to come up with a minimal running example. However, the debug keeps highlighting the destructor code lines. My Question any hint into what I should be double check in the code.

Comment: With memory corruption a player on the board, the code to check is pretty much all of it I'm afraid.

Comment: The error message is very generic coming from the `malloc`/`free` implementation. It just means that you are misusing the heap in some way (e.g. write out-of-bounds). Nothing in the shown code is directly causing this and the cause may be far disconnected from the point where the error manifests. Compile your program with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and see what details it will tell you when you run the compiled program. Alternatively run the program under valgrind or go through it in a debugger.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I just, *JUST* had this problem yesterday, with `free` throwing from the destructor. It was nothing to do with the destructor, it was an out of bounds access where the index variable, at a glance, looked like it couldn't go out of bounds.

Replace any square bracket accessing with `.at()` and see if you get an out of bounds exception. Then you can go troubleshoot that.